# Loop through a transaction file to derive average prices for products

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I am working on a data file which contains sales of products from various store chains ,e.g. supermarkets.
(Taken from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/acquire-valued-shoppers-challenge/data) in case someone is familiar).
The file contains a number of fields:

1. id - Unique customer id
2. chain - Store chain id
3. dept - An aggregate grouping of the Category (e.g. water)
4. category - The product category (e.g. sparkling water)
5. company - An id of the company that sells the item
6. brand - An id of the brand to which the item belongs
7. date - The date of purchase
8. productsize - The amount of the product purchase (e.g. 16 oz of water)
9. productmeasure - The units of the product purchase (e.g. ounces)
10. purchasequantity - The number of units purchased
11. purchaseamount - The dollar amount of the purchase
12. productprice - Product price (derived by purchaseamount/purchasequantity)

I want to calculate the average price across the transaction dataset for each product.
For this exercise, I am assuming that I can define **a unique product** by the following fields: category, brand, productsize, so that any unique product corresponds to a unique combination of those 3 fields.

So first I identify the unique items in the dataset to get a list of all the products:

```
#transactions is the name of the data frame
items <- unique(transactions %>% select(category, brand, productsize))
```

I can now use this as a lookup table for picking up the unique products from the transaction dataset and derive the average price for each one.

Since I am a newbie, I only managed to get it to work with a (not quite elegant) *for loop*:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(items)) {
  temp1 <- filter(transactions, category==items[i,1])
  temp2 <- filter(temp1, brand==items[i,2])
  temp3 <- filter(temp2, productsize==items[i,3])
  items$meanvalue[i]<- mean(temp3$productprice)
}
```

This works, but of course it is very slow. The *transaction* data frame has 480612 entries and the *items* data frame has 56658. I don't have experience with large datasets but I am sure that the problem is with the code, not so much the size.

Sample file (300 rows) in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/C3pYx05c).

**EDIT :** Found out that `summarise` works quite well with this!

```
avgPrice <- transactions %>% group_by(category, brand, productsize) %>% summarise(avgPrice = mean(productprice))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since R is vectorized, this should be much faster than using a for loop!

```
# library(tidyverse) # if needed

# get item combinations
itemCombs <- transactions %>% 
  group_by(category, brand, productsize) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(item = 1:n()) %>% 
  select(item, everything())

# append item combinations to original dataset and calculate avg price per item 
avgPrice <- transactions %>% 
  left_join(itemCombs, by = c("category", "brand", "productsize")) %>% 
  select(item, productprice) %>% 
  arrange(item) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(nItems = n(),
         sumPrice = sum(productprice)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(avgPrice = sumPrice/nItems)
```

Comment: Thank you Felix. However, I am afraid my post was a bit misleading. 
I actually wanted to create a dataset where each unique product will appear only once. But I can still derive that from the ```avgPrice``` anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can! If you do: `group_by(item) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()`, you should get the desired result.  (This basically takes the first observation per item (per unique combination of those three variables you'd mentioned.)) Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!
And thanks for clearing out for me the ```slice()``` functionality.